# is it possible to change Caret Symbol(Text Cursor) dynamically in windows system wide?

Tags: c++, window, caret

I want to change the Caret Symbol(Text Cursor) dynamically in windows and independently of applications(system wide).

i mean this one:

[image]

but i don't know if it is possible to make such utility-tool.

only i found in google was to tweak registry to change the Caret Symbol.

but once it is changed in registry, i must restart my computer.

i do not want to restart my computer for changing Caret Symbol.

is it possible to change caret sybol in windows without restart?

Comment: tag a language like 'delphi' or 'c#' to this question. It would help you to get more specific answers.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, if you are using delphi.

```
function GetCaretPosition(var APoint: TPoint): Boolean;
var w: HWND;
  aID, mID: DWORD;
begin
  Result:= False;
  w:= GetForegroundWindow;
  if w <> 0 then
  begin
    aID:= GetWindowThreadProcessId(w, nil);
    mID:= GetCurrentThreadid;
    if aID <> mID then
    begin
      if AttachThreadInput(mID, aID, True) then
      begin
        w:= GetFocus;
        if w <> 0 then
        begin
          Result:= GetCaretPos(APoint);
          ClientToScreen(w, APoint);
        end;
        AttachThreadInput(mID, aID, False);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;


//Small demo: set cursor to active caret position
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
ListBox1.Items.Clear();
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  Pt: TPoint;
begin
  if GetCaretPosition(Pt) then
  begin
    ListBox1.Items.Add(Format('Caret position %d %d', [Pt.x, Pt.y]));
//    SetCursorPos(Pt.X, Pt.Y);
  end;
end;

end.
```